# Reclassify a raster based on another one in R

Tags: r, raster

I have 2 rasters:

```
library ('raster')
r1=raster(matrix(1:4,nrow=2))
r2=raster(matrix(runif(16),nrow=4))
```

I want to reclassify all the values in the second raster that have value==1 in the first raster. Thanks!

Comment: Please make your code reproducible by adding which package is required to made available the `raster` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. For example

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(matrix(1:4, nrow=4, ncol=4))
r2 <- raster(matrix(runif(16),nrow=4))
x <- overlay(r1, r2, fun=function(x,y){ y[x==1] <- 0; y})
```

Instead of overlay you can use `calc(stack(r1, r2))`. You can also use a combination of `reclassify` and `cover`